# .htaccess - Redirect everything to homepage except one directory

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I'm creating an AngularJS app and want to avoid the # in the URL. I learned that I needed to add the following .htaccess rules to make it work:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

That worked great. However, now my calls to my web services are not working. The web service files are inside an **/api/** directory, e.g. **http://example.com/api/**. My guess is that when the api calls try to access those files, they also get redirected and break. So how can I modify the rules above to redirect everything to the homepage, except links that are going to any file inside the **api** folder? I tried to find an existing answer to this, but while there were many similar ones, none of them was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the code I needed:

```
RewriteEngine On  
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /
```

That's all you need. Got it from: https://ngmilk.rocks/2015/03/09/angularjs-html5-mode-or-pretty-urls-on-apache-using-htaccess/